# Am I at the deepest hierarchical grouping

Tags: oracle11g, crystal-reports, hierarchical-data

I'm working on a Crystal report which is grouped hierarchically. Sometimes the data goes down to a fifth-level grouping, sometimes only a 4th. I'd like to be able to tell if I'm at the deepest level of the tree, so that I can switch from using the data in the group header to using the data in the detail line, setting it to columns. I've tried to use the Maximum() function to see how deep the tree goes, but that requires a field, not just an expression.

I've also tried writing a hierarchical query in Oracle and using the MAX OVER (PARTITION BY parent) clause, but that's only bringing back the data I already have, and in addition, it seems to be forcing me to lose the level-1 lines.

**ETA:** I have checked the GroupingLevel and HierarchyLevel functions, but those don't seem to help -- they only tell me where I am, not where I'm going. When I said above that I used Maximum(), I should have clarified I meant Maximum(HierarchyLevel(blah)).

**ETA2:** Ok, say the data looks like this:

```
id  parentid
1   
2   1
3   2
4   3
5   3
6   1
7   6
8   7
9   8
10  8
11  8
```

I want something that will return True for 4, 5, 9, 10, and 11, because that's as far down the tree as I can go.

Comment: Sorry No idea how to overcome this...as my answer is nit useful deleting...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "I've tried to use the Maximum() function...but that requires a field, not just an expression." Can you give an example of your data?

Comment: So you just want to find if a record is a leaf node?

Comment: Yes, I guess that's a better way to phrase it...